# c++ copy string literal (from C)

Tags: c++, c, char

I want to save a C String to a C++ Variable. This shall than be passed to the C-API function.

The string is defined in the C-API
as

```
#define  XI_PRM_BINNING_HORIZONTAL_MODE         "binning_horizontal_mode"
```

I want to select the string in a switch

```
char * binnMode;
...
binnMode = XI_PRM_BINNING_HORIZONTAL_MODE;
```

But that fails because the C-literal is defined as `char str[]` (C++11)

I want to pass the string to a function that expects

```
xiSetParamInt(IN HANDLE hDevice, const char* prm, const int val)
```

How do I need to define `binnMode` in order to get this working?

Comment: What "fails"? Please include the verbatim error message and even better: show a [MCVE]

Comment: binnMode pointed data should be const: `const char * binnMode`

Comment: `const char * binnMode;` ?

Answer (score 6):

Notice that the parameter is `const char*`, not `char*`.

That's convenient because it's also what `binnMode` needs to be.

String literals are immutable, and (in C++) `const`. Yours is a `const char[<length+1>]` (don't know where you heard it was a `char[]`) which decays nicely to a `const char*`.

Comment: *"don't know where you heard it was a `char[]`"* - It is in C to this day. But modifying it is UB. Quite silly, really.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I quote: _"the C-literal is defined as `char str[]` (C++11)"_

Comment: I'm pretty sure strings in tapestries were immutable before the Bayeux tapestry ....

Comment: To be frank, that complete sentence is wrought with confusion on the OP's part. The double tagging is what led me to believe the OP is thinking of C here. Wasn't a critique of your answer :)

Comment: Total OT-pedantry - "AD" should *precede* the year number (**A.D. 1066**), not follow it as "BC" does.

Comment: @TobySpeight: You're right